# How to encrypt roles in Ansible using ansible vault

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-inventory, ansible-template

How to encrypt roles in Ansible using ansible vault, I have multiple roles inside one project and from source code protection perspective we want to encrypt whole roles not particular playbooks.

Comment: I think it would help if you add a little more context to your question. What are you trying to achieve and maybe a short glimpse into why ?

Answer (score 2):

But why? It sounds not logical to encyrpt/decrypt roles and playbooks. You should only do this with passwords.

If you really want to store your roles securely, you could look at alternate methods, such as `zip` [with the password function](https://superuser.com/questions/370389/how-do-i-password-protect-a-tgz-file-with-tar-in-unix).

Answer (score -1):

Yes this is feasible and I have tested it properly. Though this is not recommended and best practice to encrypt all files.

Comment: If you're going to post an answer, please make it useful for someone else that might encounter this question. An answer of "cool, I solved it" with no details of how is incredibly frustrating for someone with a problem.

Comment: find . -type f -printf "%h/\"%f\" " | xargs ansible-vault encrypt
This way you encrypt in one go.